# Implement HTTPS file server in C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, http, https, boost-asio

I would like to implement a simple file server application on Linux that would allow logged in users to upload and download files.

This file server should work with a Django application that would handle the user login/file permissions and pass download/upload HTTPS requests to the C++ file server application.

Also, it should handle multiple requests from multiple users. What is the best way to do this?  Should I use boost:asio or another library? Where should I start?

Comment: And sftp (over ssh) doesn't meet your requirements?

Comment: It might be worth clarifying why you want to do this. FTP will already allow you to do this and if you want it to have a web front end you would be better off writing it using Django.

Comment: Nick Long: I would also have a desktop client that would login using username/password and make HTTPS connections to create and update files (or parts of them).

Comment: trojanfoe: I would like to do this over HTTP(S).

Answer (score 2):

Try [cpp-netlib](http://mikhailberis.github.com/cpp-netlib/) - headers-only C++ Network Library highly influenced by Boost C++ Libraries and created by [Dean Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11274/dean-michael)

Answer (score 1):

The [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) library is a C++ library to easily code HTTP or HTTPS servers.

You could also make your file server application a [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/) or [SCGI](http://python.ca/scgi/) client of your web server (the one running Django).

Answer (score 0):

[DAG](http://dag.wieers.com/howto/ssh-http-tunneling/) allows tunneling SSH over HTTP, and might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty good list of HTTP libraries http://kukuruku.co/hub/cpp/a-cheat-sheet-for-http-libraries-in-c